# I purchased two tickets to Universal Studios Hollywood for two people but both tickets have my name on it

Tags: tickets, los-angeles, universal-studios

I'm currently scheduled to travel the US and Canada for a few weeks and am going to also be stopping by LA. My travel partner and I decided to pay a visit to Universal Studios and purchased tickets via an online platform (Klook in case anyone's curious).

Upon receiving the tickets, I realized that both tickets have my name on it (I made the payment). This wasn't a concern to me, since both tickets are valid but I noticed on the "Important Instructions and Terms of Use" section of the ticket that it says:

> This ticket is only valid for the person named on it.

Would it be a problem if I used the two tickets for myself and my partner? I'm hoping not because the tickets are non-refundable and I paid quite a bit of money for them, but hopefully someone can shed some light on this issue.

Thanks.

#### EDIT

I also just noticed that it says the ticket is:

> Valid for one (1) guest admission and one (1) Universal Express ticket to Universal Studios Hollywood.

Does this mean that I could have just purchased one ticket and brought my partner along?

Sorry for the jumble of questions, I'm just very confused by the language.

Comment: Regarding the guest question, no, you need two tickets.  The ticket is for one guest, not you plus a guest, so the one guest *is* you, as a (so-called) "guest" of Universal Studios Hollywood.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is still the case, but I visited the Studios 3 years ago and on the ticket it said:

> This ticket is only valid for the person named on it

Infact I made the payment, as per your case, but I chose 2 different names.

It's better if you contact the Studios directly and explain the problem.